# Restrict AJAX file uploads using a time limit

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to know if it's possible to restrict the user from uploading files via AJAX, if they have uploaded x files within y minutes then the user will be able to upload files again after z minutes.

I tried to write a simple PHP script:

```php
if (count($_FILES) >= $this->uploadsPerSession) {
    dd('sorry, you cannot upload more than ' . $this->uploadsPerSession . ' files at once.');
}

if (!session()->has('file_upload_count')) {
    session([
        'file_upload_count' => count($_FILES),
    ]);
} else {
    $currentUploadCount = session()->get('file_upload_count');
    $s = $currentUploadCount + count($_FILES);
    // If it exceeds, create a timeout variable
    if ($currentUploadCount > $this->uploadsPerSession) {
        $selectedTime = date('h:i:s');
        $endTime = strtotime("+1 minute", strtotime($selectedTime));
        $x = date('h:i:s', $endTime);

        session([
            'next_upload_timestamp' => $x,
        ]);

        // reset upload count
        session()->put('file_upload_count', 0);

        dd('sorry, cannot upload now. please try again at ' . $x);
    }

    if (!session()->has('next_upload_timestamp') || session()->has('next_upload_timestamp')
        && session()->get('next_upload_timestamp') > date('h:i:s')) {
        \Session::put('file_upload_count', $s);
        dd('uploaded');
    }
}
```

This script doesn't have any file upload yet as I was trying to see if whether it would work by storing in a session.

Comment: you can simply put a throttle limit on the upload route

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and it works! Never thought of it though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @N69S comment, I resolved it by simply adding a throttle limit to the route:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['throttle:50,5']], function () {
    Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/test-func', 'FileController@testFunc')->name('test-func');
});
```

The above example is used in a Laravel application.